# How to generate TFW files for a list of images?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, batch

I have a few digital images that are not georeferenced. E.g.:

```
Img01.tif  
Img02.tif  
...
Img99.tif
```

On the other hand, I have a text file, which contains georeferencing information for these images. E.g., I have a file `c:\tfws\list.txt` which contains the following information:

```
Img01.tfw 0.25 0 0 - 0.25 456258,125 4569852,125  
Img02.tfw 0.25 0 0 - 0.25 456586,125 4570001,125   
Img03.tfw 0.25 0 0 - 0.25 456952,125 4570300,125  
...
Img99.tfw 0.25 0 0 - 0.25 458412,125 4575123,125
```

I need to generate a TFW file for each image in the text file. E.g. create a file named `C:\tfws\img??.tfw` containing the following information:

```
0.25  
0  
0  
-0.25  
456258,125  
4569852,125
```

Does anyone know of a tool able to generate these TFW files automatically?

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE! I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Would you be able to provide more details, please? Are you using any GIS software already?

Comment: It might help if you can show a sample of the data that you would like to convert to TFW file. Also, it might help if you tell us what you've already tried, what worked for you and what didn't. You can just edit your question (click edit below the question) to add these very useful details.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question given the author's recent edits.

Comment: i think this is just a programming question and not within the scope of GISSE..

Comment: I think it's borderline because some knowledge of the [world file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) is required and I can imagine other GIS users running into something similar, even if the solution in this case is simple text manipulation.

Comment: I think question is relevant for gis.se.  There's a bad gotcha here - the question is tagged with [tag:geotiff], but asks about tfw files.  Geotiff embeds registration into the tiff file itself.  When there's a conflict between embedded registration and the registration in the tfw file, strange things can happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't nice code, but for your specific circumstance, here is some python that should save typing them out by hand:

```py
f = open('list.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    lineparts = line.split(' ')
    outfile = open(lineparts[0], 'w')
    for i in range(1, 4):
        outfile.write(lineparts[i] + '\n')
    outfile.write(lineparts[4] + lineparts[5] + '\n')
    for i in range(6, 8):
        outfile.write(lineparts[i] + '\n')
```

(real code would sanity check, but I assume you can check the results)

Comment: (1) Did you notice the whitespace between the leading minus signs and the values: `- 0.25`? It would be bad to split those with a newline! (2) It seems you just write out to a single file which includes the intended names of the world files. What's needed is output to the worldfiles separately.

Comment: (1) I did notice, but somehow read the output as requiring a line with a - on it. Tried again. (2) It outputs separate files (since outfile gets open()ed inside the lines loop) - I did test this.

Comment: Good--I didn't catch that.  I was thrown off by the outputting of eight fields; I had mistakenly thought one of them was the file name. How do you get eight fields in addition to the file name?  I find only seven.  Did you actually open one of the output files to check your code?

Comment: There are 8 fields - the name, and 7 values. range(6,8) produces [6, 7]. range(1,4) produces [1,2,3].

Comment: Thanks--I was not aware of that strange definition of `range`, but in retrospect it's clear from the details of your code so I should have been able to figure that out.  Incidentally, don't your inner for-loop bodies need some more indentation?

Comment: Thanks for the indent hint. Looks like tabs don't copy too well...

Comment: Sorry that not has been able to review it before, I have enough work. Thank you very much, works perfectly

Comment: Can you please mark one of the answers as "ok" to close this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

AWK is perhaps the most effective tool for such text conversion (although if you're familiar with Perl you might prefer it, out of habit): it was designed for exactly this kind of one-off quick reformatting work.

Here is the full AWK code to perform the requested operation on the input specified:

```awk
BEGIN {OFS="\n"}
{print $2, $3, $4, $5 $6, $7, $8 > $1}
```

(The absence of a comma between `$5` and `$6` is no misprint: it concatenates the minus sign `-` with the following value `0.25`.)

This can be typed directly into AWK, but it's better to put it into a file called, say, `tfw.awk`.  It would then be invoked from a command line prompt like

```
tfw list.txt
```

or

```
awk -f tfw.awk list.txt
```

(if the system environment has not been set up to recognize .awk files as executable).

It will execute instantaneously, leaving behind the specified files (and overwriting them if they already exist).

Every Unix system comes with a copy of AWK and there is a [free GNU version for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).  I just downloaded the GNU distribution and ran it on a Windows 64 workstation; it works fine.

Comment: Sorry that not has been able to review it before, I have enough work. Thank you very much, works perfectly.