# How to make a geo reference image using GeoTool based on a matrix mapped data?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoprocessing, geotiff-tiff, geotools

My ultimate objective is to make a geo reference image and make it as a raster layer to overlay the image above my openlayers map.

I have a set of geo coordinate data, and each coordinate is assigned to a value. The value is used to represent a color code.

```
cell           coordinate           value        Color
[x0 , y0]      [125.0 , 36.0]         1          Yellow
[x0 , y1]      [125.0 , 36.1]         1          Yellow
.
.
[x1, y0]       [125.1 , 36.0]         1          Yellow
[x1, y1]       [125.1 , 36.1]         2          Orange
.
.
[x2, y0]       [125.2 , 36.0]         1          Yellow
[x2, y1]       [125.2 , 36.1]         2          Orange
[x2, y2]       [125.2 , 36.2]         3          Red
[x2, y2]       [125.2 , 36.3]         3          Red
```

Hence, I will have a matrix mapped data which looks like below:
[image: matrix mapped data]

Now I want to create a geo reference image with inner projection : `EPSG 4326` and outter projection : `EPSG 900913`

**Can this be done by using GeoTool? If can, then how?**

Help is needed.

Comment: I don't know geotool, but the first thing I would do is create a tfw file in EPSG 4326 (you know the upper left (125, 36) and the pixel size (0.1). Then project this in EPSG 900913.

Comment: how to create a tfw file by programming?

Comment: multiple posts on the topic. See this one for instance : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61011/how-to-generate-tfw-files-for-a-list-of-images

Comment: does the solution need to be in geotools ?

Comment: Need to be done at client side by JSP. Any other recommendation? Or else, you can also recommend some useful source, so that I can ask the server guy to do it.