# Batch Georeferencing in arcGIS 10.1.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, georeferencing, batch

I work for a government utility company. Our maps are broken down into 500x500 square meter grids. We have scanned images (TIFF) of these maps that we need to overlay and digize. The maps and the scans are saved in different folders with corresponding map and scan being named for example 5049.dwg and 5049.Tiff respectively. In the past we have been Georeferencing in AutoCAD but we migrated to GIS for better accuracy. Each of these scans are the same size but have different coordinates as they are building blocks of a bigger map,  like a jigsaw of sorts. Is there a way to automate the batch Georeferencing of these scans using either python or model builder?.
The question was marked a duplicate, in this case the coordinates of each image is different.

Comment: you know the size of the image so pixel size can be geo-referenced to the top left - so you can batch it in python http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61011/how-to-generate-tfw-files-for-a-list-of-images

Comment: What do you mean with that the coordinates for each image is different? Are they not supposed to be side by side?